# JQuery won't call on image click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

So I've created a jquery call to check if an image in a series of images with the same account name: `.account-img`, are clicked.

I load the images through PHP like so:

```
<?php
    foreach($accountsArray as &$acc) {
        echo ('
            <!--<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">-->
                <img class="img-thumbnail account-img" src="https://twitter.com/'.$acc['screen_name'].'/profile_image?size=original" alt="Profile Image" id="img-'.$acc['screen_name'].'" />
            <!--</div>-->
        ');
    }
?>
```

Shorthand for the image is as follows:

```
<img class="img-thumbnail account-img" src="https://twitter.com/BBCNews/profile_image?size=original" alt="Profile Image" id="img-BBCNews" />
```

Here is the JQuery i use to call the image clicks:

```
$('.account-img').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    var name = id[1];
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        alert(name);
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

It won't be a single element because of the PHP code i'm actually using. it will be multiple elements and i want to perform an action based on each individual image. But because my ID isn't known beforehand, I need to do it this way

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? It seems very odd that you would actually want to add multiple `click` handlers to a single element in a loop.

Comment: and id is `img-BBCNews` not `bbcnews`

Comment: There is no id `#bbcnews` in your code as well.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It won't be a single element because of the PHP code i'm actually using. it will be multiple elements and i want to perform an action based on each individual image. But because my ID isn't known beforehand, I need to do it this way

Comment: @madcrazydrumma: `$('#bbcnews')` represents a single element.  If you have multiple elements with the same `id` then your HTML is invalid and the behavior of the code is undefined.

Comment: Updated the code there was an error, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to user `click` trigger for that as below code.... And for get current image click you use `this` inside click trigger....

```
$('.account-img').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There would be no reason to foreach the element if you're going to add a click handler on it. Removing the foreach would be enough.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.account-img').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    var name = id[1];
    console.log(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img-thumbnail account-img" src="https://twitter.com/BBCNews/profile_image?size=original" alt="Profile Image" id="img-BBCNews" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.account-img').each(function() {
        var id = $('#img-BBCNews').attr('id').split('-');
        var name = id[1];
        $('#img-BBCNews').on('click', function() {
            alert(name);
        });
    });
});
```